# Grails named query - find by association

Tags: grails, associations, named-query

I want to create a named query that will find all objects of one class, based on a property (or properties) of child class properties.

I want to be able to find all Bars where Foo.me == "some string"

So, I have this, and it doesn't work:

```
class Foo {
    String me
}

class Bar {
    Foo foo

    static namedQueries = {
        findByFooMe { meStr ->
            eq(foo.me, meStr)
        }
    }
}
```

What does the correct syntax look like please?  Also, how does it change if Bar hasMany Foos, and I want to find all Bars where one of its Foo,me properties is "search string"?

i.e.

```
class Bar {
    static hasMany [foos: Foo]
}
```

Comment: I would go with @Joshua's answer but you can also use `eq('foo.me', meStr)` as a minor modification to what you have in question right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wouldn't recommend using `findBy` as the prefix to a named query, you are close to having the right implementation. Here is an updated version with a new name for the query too.

```
static namedQueries = {
    locateByFooMe { meStr ->
        foo {
          eq('me', meStr)
        }
    }
}
```

If you change your relationship to a collection (One to Many) just make sure the property name `foo` (in this case) changes to whatever you change it to (`foos` in your question) and the above query will still continue to work.